# How to fix numeric keypad ignored even when numlock is on Windows XP running inside VMWare Player?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-xp, vmware, vmware-player

We have a legacy app that cannot be installed anywhere else other than Windows XP. Users launch that VM on their workstations to use the app. This solution is currently being used on many computers, and it works reasonably well.

Last week, we prepared a Windows 10 Pro workstation for a remote employee. That employee connects to AnyDesk, then can start VMWare Player 15.

However, unlike on any other workstation, on this one, the numeric keypad does not work inside the VM. This makes data entry for that employee quite annoying. We tried setting the Registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators` to `2`, we tried forcing numlock `on` in VMWare's BIOS, and we also tried re-installing VMWare Player, nothing has fixed the issue so far. It's the same player version, the same virtual machine (copied every time), etc. The only difference is the Windows 10 host environment; this last machine is more up-to-date than the others as it was just prepared.

When pressing `4`, for example, the cursor moves left, just as if numlock was off.

Has anyone seeen this, and what could be the resolution?

### ** Update 1 **

I have re-installed everything, again, after noticing this :

[image: Issue with enhenced keyboard not installed]

The checkbox to install that component was selected, and there were no errors during installation. The computer (i.e. both guest and host) have been restarted.

The error is still there, complaining that the enhanced keyboard is not installed. It is. I installed it, twice.

### ** Update 2 **

I updated to VMWare Player 16 on that workstation, then re-installed the Guest tools using the "complete" install option. Still the same issue; the numeric keypad acts as if numlock was off regardless everything I try.

Comment: As a workaround you can use the on-screen virtual keyboard. https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2045533

Comment: Did you install VMware Tools in the XP Guest and then assign num lock while the mouse is active in the Guest.

Comment: I have installed the Guest addition, yes, as I always do, but I have not seen this "num lock while the mouse is active in the Guest" option.

Comment: Interesting. I have VMware Workstation Pro V16 and just tested on my desktop with LogiTech Keyboard with Num Lock feature. I ran XP Pro, opened Notepad, and typed on the number keys and nothing - then I pressed Num Lock (inside the XP machine) and now number keys work fine. I did not enable the VMware Enhanced Keyboard feature. You may need to upgrade to V16 or to Workstation (even Trial to test) . Certainly working here.

Comment: I have installed VMWare Player 16, re-installed all Guest addition (complete), nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing not only key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators to 2.
But also do a search of the entire registry for the parameter name "InitialKeyboardIndicators" and everywhere change it to 2.
It helped me in a similar situation.

If this doesn't work for you, try adding a simple VBS script to your XP startup:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"
```